# SQL Server count of mutual friends

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to build a query. The requirement is to get the number of mutual friends between two users. This I need to do for a single userId passed as a parameter. The result however will be recursive. It will be like a tree. The following table structure will give you an idea about what is the requirement:

```
DECLARE @Person TABLE
(ID INT PRIMARY KEY,
Name VARCHAR(25))

DECLARE @Friendship TABLE
(PersonID INT,
 FriendID INT)

--Person table entry
INSERT @Person 
SELECT 1, 'A' UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'B' UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'C' UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'D' 

--Person:Friend relationship entry
INSERT @Friendship 
SELECT 1, 2 UNION 
SELECT 1, 4 UNION 
SELECT 2, 1 UNION 
SELECT 2, 3 UNION 
SELECT 2, 4 UNION 
SELECT 3, 2 UNION 
SELECT 3, 4 UNION 
SELECT 4, 1 UNION 
SELECT 4, 2 UNION 
SELECT 4, 3

SELECT DISTINCT F1.*, F2.PersonID AS MutualFriend
FROM @Friendship AS F1
INNER JOIN @Friendship AS F2 ON F2.PersonID <> F1.PersonID AND F2.FriendID = F1.FriendID
INNER JOIN @Person AS P1 ON P1.ID = F1.PersonID 
INNER JOIN @Person AS P2 ON P2.ID = F2.FriendID 
JOIN @Person AS P3 ON P3.ID = F2.FriendID
WHERE F1.PersonID = 3--The person for which friends and mutual friends need to be found
ORDER BY F1.PersonID
```

The above is a sample query giving the following output:

```
PersonID    FriendID    MutualFriend
3           2           1
3           2           4
3           4           1
3           4           2
```

As you can see, 1 is not a friend of 3 still it is there in the list. The desired output of the query is:

```
PersonID    FriendID    MutualFriend
3           2           4
3           4           2
```

Can someone help me in this query? Preferably I would like the count of mutual friends between two persons.

Answer (score 1):

According to the desired output try **Replacing** your select for this:

```
SELECT F1.*, MAX(F2.PersonID) AS MutualFriend
FROM @Friendship AS F1
INNER JOIN @Friendship AS F2 ON F2.PersonID <> F1.PersonID AND F2.FriendID = F1.FriendID
INNER JOIN @Person AS P1 ON P1.ID = F1.PersonID 
INNER JOIN @Person AS P2 ON P2.ID = F2.FriendID 
JOIN @Person AS P3 ON P3.ID = F2.FriendID
WHERE F1.PersonID = 3
group by F1.personID,F1.FriendID
```

Comment: Good one dear. Keep it.

Comment: This query is giving me the wrong answer. Just change the insert values to INSERT @Friendship 
SELECT 1, 2 UNION 
SELECT 1, 4 UNION 
SELECT 2, 1 UNION 
SELECT 2, 3 UNION 
SELECT 3, 2 UNION 
SELECT 3, 4 UNION 
SELECT 4, 1 UNION 
SELECT 4, 2 UNION 
SELECT 4, 3  and the result is broken. 1 is not a mutual friend of 3&4 yet it is in the list.